# Selecting an element of a matrix that contains specific string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have the following matrix:

```
l = {{{"black_pepper", "cabbage", "carrot", "cumin", "olive_oil", 
 "onion", "potato", "TURMERIC"}, {"bell_pepper", "cayenne", 
 "cilantro", "cumin", "garlic", "lemon_juice", "olive_oil", 
 "parsley"}, {"butter", "cayenne", "coconut", "onion", 
 "roasted_peanut", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar"}}};
```

I am trying to select the element that has `"TURMERIC"` in it. So the output should be the first element of `l`. I tried:

```
Select[l, StringContainsQ@# == "TURMERIC" &]
```

but it returns empty list. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a list of lists of strings, so you need a selection function that acts on a list. Try `Select[l, MemberQ[#, StringContainsQ[#, "TURMERIC"] &] &]`. (Can't test since I only have *gedanken Mathematica* currently.)

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thanks but when I run your code, it returns empty list as well.

Comment: Hmm, sorry; try this instead: `Select[l, MemberQ[#, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "TURMERIC"]] &]`

Comment: `Select[Catenate@l, MemberQ[#, "TURMERIC"] &]` or `Select[Catenate@l, MemberQ[#, "TURMERIC"] &]//Flatten` (or `Cases[l, {___, "TURMERIC", ___}, -1]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a somewhat superfluous first level in `l`, so we map the operator form of select over it. Moreover, we just need `MemberQ`, not `StringContainsQ`, no?

```
Select[MemberQ["TURMERIC"]] /@ l
```

> {{{"black_pepper", "cabbage", "carrot", "cumin", "olive_oil", "onion",
>       "potato", "TURMERIC"}}}

Comment: Thanks Select[l, MemberQ[#, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "TURMERIC"]] &] works if there is no {{{. I need the out put to be the whole element though. If you read the question, I have said I needed the elements to be in the format: {"black_pepper", "cabbage", "carrot", "cumin", "olive_oil", 
 "onion", "potato", "TURMERIC"}